# vinyl plank flooring, entry way door trim question

Tags: doors, trim, vinyl-flooring

I am installing vinyl plank flooring. I am stuck at the door. The problem is that I have a gap (for expansion) that is near to entry door. I want to hide this gap as this looks ugly (see image attached).

Please suggest how I can hide this gap. Note this is entry way door. Any information will be really helpful.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed your floor properly as long as it is maintaining the minimum gap at the door, but you needed also make room for a transition strip which requires about an inch of room from the door.

To include a transition strip I made my cut about 1 inch away from the surface where the transition strip was to go. Then the metal track that holds the transition strip in place still allow the 1/2 inch minimum required for the transition strip and the floor to work together. After setting the transition strip in place it cover the edge of the floor and kept the minimum requirements needed for they allow for the expansion and contraction. I included a few pictures to show what I have left.

Since there was no clean way in my eye to terminate the transition strip, I let it run from trim edge to trim edge as Illustrated one picture but since it blended in with the flow of the floor, it is not highlighted very well. I included another picture that I have not trimmed out yet

[image: w trim]

[image: no trim]

I do not have any pics of the process, but some of the space was too tight on some of the doors and needed to be cut in place. I used a multi-tool and a straight edge to do this but it can be done with a razor knife with much care and a straight edge. I also modified the transition strip to make it more narrow. I do not like transitions strips as it is, but the nature of the floor requires them

Comment: I edited the answer to show the finished product with the transition strips

Comment: Actually I was able to find a t molding from HD today. I plan to cut some of the flooring to make space for to with drummel tool. Hope that’s alright?!!

Comment: Yup, Dremel tool works well, better than a razor knife. On the cutting of the floor, I stopped my cut 1/2" from the ends of the  transition strip, and I removed 1" of the ribs on the ends on the underside of the transition strip so the floor could move in all directions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I would have cut those planks longer so they extended under the door...

I would use a bevelled trim to cover the edge now, usually they are only 1 or 1.5" wide, but wider ones can sometimes be found.

Comment: This is an exterior door with threshold. Vinyl plank requires an expansion gap. Short of removing the door threshold how canine run under the door? And how is gap maintained if you did get plank under the door?